# Restructuring SQL query based upon the table division

Tags: mysql, sql

I had a working query that I framed this way.

```
SELECT b.name AS name, b.id AS userid, b.gender AS sex, b.dob AS dob, b.hide_age AS hideage, b.hide_distance AS hidedist, b.interests AS interests,
$distVal * DEGREES(ACOS(LEAST(1.0, COS(RADIANS(a.latitude)) * COS(RADIANS(b.latitude)) * COS(RADIANS(a.longitude) - RADIANS(b.longitude)) + SIN(RADIANS(a.latitude))
* SIN(RADIANS(b.latitude))))) AS distance FROM users AS a
JOIN users AS b
WHERE b.id != :user AND a.id = :user AND b.country = :country AND FIND_IN_SET(b.gender, a.interested) AND YEAR(FROM_DAYS(DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE(), b.dob))) BETWEEN :fromage and :toage AND
b.id NOT IN (SELECT swp_to FROM swipes WHERE swp_from = a.id AND first_swp != 'rewind') AND
b.id NOT IN (SELECT swp_from FROM swipes WHERE swp_to = a.id AND second_swp NOT IN ('pending', 'rewind')) AND
a.latitude between b.latitude - 2 and b.latitude + 2 and
a.longitude between b.longitude - 2 and b.longitude + 2
HAVING distance < :maxdist ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 30
```

In the above query the `users` table joins with itself. However, the fields in the users table were becoming too long so I created a new table called `attributes` and moved some fields from `users` table to `attributes` table. The fields are `hide_age`, `hide_dist`, `latitude` and `longitude`. Now, I am trying to re-frame the above query adding the newly created `attributes` table by joining it. However, that is not giving me the correct result.

What I tried:

```
SELECT CONCAT(b.first_name, ' ', b.last_name) AS name, b.id AS userid, b.gender AS sex, b.dob AS dob, d.hide_age AS hideage, d.hide_dist AS hidedist, b.interests AS interests,
$distVal * DEGREES(ACOS(LEAST(1.0, COS(RADIANS(c.latitude)) * COS(RADIANS(d.latitude)) * COS(RADIANS(c.longitude) - RADIANS(d.longitude)) + SIN(RADIANS(c.latitude))
* SIN(RADIANS(d.latitude))))) AS distance FROM users AS a
LEFT JOIN attributes AS c ON a.id = c.user
JOIN users AS b
JOIN attributes AS d
WHERE b.id != :user AND d.user = :user AND a.id = :user AND b.country = :country AND FIND_IN_SET(b.gender, c.interested_in) AND YEAR(FROM_DAYS(DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE(), b.dob))) BETWEEN :fromage and :toage AND
b.id NOT IN (SELECT swp_to FROM swipes WHERE swp_from = a.id AND first_swp != 'rewind') AND
b.id NOT IN (SELECT swp_from FROM swipes WHERE swp_to = a.id AND second_swp NOT IN ('pending', 'rewind')) AND
c.latitude between d.latitude - 2 and d.latitude + 2 and
c.longitude between d.longitude - 2 and d.longitude + 2
HAVING distance < :maxdist ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 30
```

How can I frame the 1st query correctly with the new `attributes` table? The `id` from the `users` table which is the user id is the `user` field in the `attributes` table to connect both the tables.

**SAMPLE DATA**

users table

```
id    name      gender
1     John      male
2     Shiva     male
3     Emily     female
4     Krishna   male
```

attributes table

```
id    user    latitude
1     1       10.25
2     2       10.25
3     3       10.25
4     4       10.25
```

This latitude field was first part of `users` table. Later moved to `attributes` table. The `swipes` table has nothing to do with `attributes` table so I am ignoring that here as a sample.

**Current Result:** Only returns two rows from user table 1 and 2 and it ignores 3 and 4.

**Expected Result:** Need all 4 records to show as it was being shown from the first query.

Comment: What's wrong with the results it's giving? Please post sample data and the desired result.

Comment: Why do you use `LEFT JOIN`? Are there users with no attributes?

Comment: @Barmar sample data posted.

Comment: @Barmar No, all the users must have a record in the attributes table. But even if I use JOIN instead of LEFT JOIN, the result is still the same.

Comment: As general advice, don't use `LEFT JOIN` when you don't need it, it has poorer performance than `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: @Barmar Sure, will keep that in mind. But, any solution to this problem?

Comment: I updated the answer with a new solution a half hour ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing multiple joins, define a view that joins the two tables.

```
CREATE VIEW users_and_attributes AS
SELECT u.id AS user_id, u.name, u.gender, ..., a.id AS attribute_id, a.hide_age, a.hide_dist, a.latitude, ...
FROM users AS u
JOIN attributes AS a ON a.user = u.id
```

Then you should be able to use the original query, just replacing `users` with the view name. Change:

```
FROM users AS a
JOIN users AS b
```

to

```
FROM users_and_attributes AS a
JOIN users_and_attributes AS b
```

Since the two tables both have duplicate column name `id`, you need to give aliases to those columns in the view, and refer to those aliases in the updated query. So `a.id` and `b.id` become `a.user_id` and `b.user_id`.

Comment: I have tried that already. Even with that it doesn't return the accurate result that the 1st query did.

Comment: Then you'll need to update the question with sample data and the desired result. It would probably be best to create a sqlfiddle.

Comment: Oh wait, I didn't see that you were joining with attributes twice.

Comment: But I still think this should be the fix. Just make sure that in the `WHERE` clause, all the `c` correspond to `a` in the original query, and `d` correspond to `b`.

Comment: Yes, the attributes are joined twice for both users `a` and `b` separately. If you still need the sample data please let me know.

Comment: Yes, I have taken care of that. The `b` corresponds to `d` and `c` corresponds to `a`.

Comment: Tried creating view in `phpMyAdmin`. Returns error `#1060 - Duplicate column name 'id'`.

Comment: Then you'll need to list all the columns explicitly so you can leave out the duplicates.

Comment: Seriously? Oh man..! There are about 40 fields including both 

Comment: Do you need to get both of them from both tables? If some are redundant you can leave them out of the view.

Comment: You could use `*` for one of the tables and list the columns explicitly for the other.

Comment: Can I use * for both and have a work around for the duplicate column like id? Because suppose I manually do this right now but in future I may encounter is multiple times with even 60-70 or more fields. That time this will be an issue. I never used view before so I am unaware of the technicalities.

Comment: Sorry, I wish there were a way.

Comment: No problem. Thanks Barmar. This really helped. The real help was because of you the last 1 hr I spent with VIEWS, made me learn how VIEWS works and it's amazing. I wish I knew this earlier because now that I realized how it works I feel I could have used it in other past projects for better results. But it's better late than never and you are my tutor for today. Thanks Good Sir! Or, as we say in India, "Dhanyawad Guruji"!